# Python dictionary sum

Tags: python, regex, parsing, csv, dictionary

Hi guys I have question how to sum same IP adresses in dictionary.
I have input file, that file looks like:

```
IP           , Byte
10.180.176.61,3669
10.164.134.193,882
10.164.132.209,4168
10.120.81.141,4297
10.180.176.61,100
```

My move is to open that file and parse IP address with number after comma so I can sum all bytes for one IP address. So i can get result like:

```
IP 10.180.176.61 , 37669
```

My code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re,sys, os
from collections import defaultdict

f     = open('splited/small_file_1000000.csv','r')
o     = open('gotovo1.csv','w')

list_of_dictionaries = {}

for line in f:
    if re.search(r'\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.*',line):
        line_ip = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}',line)[0]
        line_by = re.findall(r'\,\d+',line)[0]
        line_b = re.sub(r'\,','',line_by)

        list_of_dictionaries['IP']  = line_ip
        list_of_dictionaries['VAL'] = int(line_b)


c = defaultdict(int)
for d in list_of_dictionaries:
    c[d['IP']] += d['VAL']

print c
```

Any idea would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read your file and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to sum up the totals per IP address:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv


def read_csv(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        reader.next()    # Skip header
        for row in reader:
            ip, bytes = row
            yield ip, int(bytes)


totals = Counter()
for ip, bytes in read_csv('data.txt'):
    totals[ip] += bytes

print totals
```

Output:

```
Counter({'10.120.81.141': 4297, '10.164.132.209': 4168, '10.180.176.61': 3769, '10.164.134.193': 882})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like the example you provided you don't need regular expressions to parse it. Just split the line using the comma:

> ```
> list_of_dictionaries = {}
> with open('splited/small_file_1000000.csv', 'r') as f:
>      header = f.readline()
>      for line in f:
>              ip, bytes = line.split(',')
>              if list_of_dictionaries.has_key(ip):
>                  list_of_dictionaries[ip] += int(bytes.strip())
>              else:
>                  list_of_dictionaries[ip] = int(bytes.strip())
> OUT: {'10.180.176.61': 3769, '10.164.134.193': 882, '10.164.132.209': 4168, '10.120.81.141': 4297}
> ```